# necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of solution in the space $W^{k,p}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am learning about weak derivatives and sobolev space. In particular I need help to learn the proving strategy/technique.

I have trouble proving on how to show a solution belongs to some sobolev space. A particular problem I came across is to prove
$$ u\in W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$$
**if and only if** $\exists$ a sequence of functions $\{u_m\}\subset C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap L^p (\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that

1. $$ \|u_m-u\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}\to 0\quad\text{as}\quad m\to\infty$$
   and
2. $$\|D^{\alpha}u_m-D^{\alpha}u_n\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}\to 0\quad\text{as}\quad m,n\to\infty\quad\text{for each}\quad |\alpha|\le k $$

**Questions**
Could anyone sketch a proof of above?
What books contain proofs of this kind? So that I can pick up the proving technique quickly...

Comment: I think this is not about a criterion for testing whether something is in a given Sobolev space, but, rather, the assertion (for you to prove) that smooth functions (in fact, test functions) are dense in every Sobolev space.

Comment: @paulgarrett: On"smooth functions are dense in every sobolev space". How do I show this? Or in what book can I look this up?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all graduate-level PDE texts will have this classical result, my personal favorite is Evans'. If you just google "global approximation of smooth functions", any number of proofs will pop up, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523503/approximation-in-sobolev-spaces) was a previous post in which a user had questions about Evans' proof.

**EDIT:** Broad strokes of iff proof: Forward direction: If $u\in W^{k,p}$, then we have a sequence of smooth functions satisfying 1.,2. by the global approximation theorem. For the reverse direction, if we have a sequence $u_m$ for which $D^\alpha u_m\rightarrow D^\alpha u$ for each $\alpha$, then by completeness of $W^{k,p}$ it must be that $u\in W^{k,p}$.

Comment: I came across this proof in Evan's book. However I am looking for help in writing if and only if type of proof. I often get lost when people ask me to prove necessary and sufficient conditions. Would be helpful if I can find more examples of this kind.

Comment: Only one direction of the iff is nontrivial: $W^{k,p}$ is complete (a separate, but nontrivial important result) so any sequence in $W^{k,p}$ that converges will be in $W^{k,p}$... Thus the other direction is where the only work happens.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean? 1) which direction ? 2) How does this "iff" type of proof relates to the the sentence you wrote $W^{k,p}$ is complete? Do you mean...the proof of $u\in W^{k,p}$ is done if we can show the limit of $u_m$ and the limit of $D^{\alpha} u_m$ can be found in $L^p?$

Comment: Looking at your edited answer, "The forward direction" can be regarded as the proof of necessity, which is much of 5.3.3.Evans' proof about? And the reverse implication is the proof of sufficiency?

Comment: Also, on "completeness of $W^{k,p}$, do you mean completeness of $L^p$?

Comment: @ charlestoncrabb: could you please respond? (it is strange that stack exchange does not display "@someone" properly for your name, it happens very often and i hope this can be fixed one day)

Comment: @ charlestoncrabb: Looking at your edited answer again...the forward direction is the proof of necessity, and the reverse direction is the proof of sufficiency?

Comment: Completeness of $W^{k,p}$ follows from completeness of $L^p$, yes, since each derivative $D^\alpha u$ lies in $L^p$.

Comment: As far as terminology, suppose the statement $A\Rightarrow B$ is true. Then $A$ is a sufficient condition for $B$ to hold, and $B$ necessarily holds when $A$ does. Thus in a biconditional we say that $A$ is necessary and sufficient for $B$. In proving the forward direction, you are proving sufficiency of the first statement/necessity of the second

Comment: @ chalestoncrabb: First, your 3rd sentence. I think, you meant $B$ is necessary and sufficient for $A$. Next, "first/second statement"and forward/reverse direction" corresponds to what?

Comment: @ chalestoncrabb: on your answer "by completeness of $W^{k,p}$ there must be that $u\in W^{k,p}$." Do you mean that one need to show the weak derivative indeed exists? I mean, if denote $u_{\alpha}=D^{\alpha}u$, then one needs to show $|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}u_{\alpha}\phi(x)dx-|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}u_m\phi(x)dx|\to 0$ as $m\to\infty$ for some $\phi\in C_0^{\infty}?$